# How to enable Python automatically after restarting my Centos 6.5 machine?

Tags: shell-script, centos, python3, scl

I am using Software Collections Repository (SCL) to install Python 3 package "rh-python36" on Centos 6 machine. I am adding this script to .sh file located in the /etc/profile.d directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/rh/rh-python36/enable
export X_SCLS="`scl enable rh-python36 'echo $X_SCLS'`"
```

I am not sure what is wrong. Is there's another solution for such a problem?